# Is there a way to capture List element xpath without using list index . Using selenium with java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Can we capture list element using attribute as well or it can only be captured using index value.

This is not working :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='interview-question']/div/div/ul/li[@id='tablist1-panel2']")).click();
```

This is working:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='interview-question']/div/div/ul/li[2]")).click();
```

Comment: It can be clicked using the attribute as well. Could you please share relevant page source for better understanding.

Comment: You can possibly extract your index with regex "tablist1-panel".

Comment: @BhargavMarpu   view-source:http://qaclickacademy.com/interview.php